Flutter development, including webview related content, printing a lot of "updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame." How to remove it
Flutter development, including webview related content, printing a lot of "updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame." How to remove it? Xiaomi phones with Android 13 system.
Remove "updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame."
